# Get AD group members with ADSI - Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, adsi

I cannot use the Active Directory Module to get the SamAccountName of the users in a specific AD-group. How can I do this with ADSI?

I've tried:

```
$Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://DN of the AD group"
$Group.Member | ForEach-Object {
    $Searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samAccountName=$_)"
    $searcher.FindOne().Properties
}
```

But I see this message:

> The samAccountName search filter is invalid.

How can I do this?

Comment: Read the error again - there's an `o` missing from `samAccuntName`

Comment: Same error message

Comment: That error message doesn't look like any error message that would be generated by the code you show.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways around this as I see it, there might be an easier way of doing it though.

One is to search for all users which's `memberOf` attribute has the `DistinguishedName` of the group (this might be the less cumbersome approach):

```
$group = 'CN=myGroup, OU=myOU, DC=myDomain'
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(memberof=$group))"
$members = foreach($member in $searcher.FindAll()) {
    $member.Properties.samaccountname
}
```

The other way around is using the same approach as you're using in your question:

```
$group = 'CN=myGroup, OU=myOU, DC=myDomain'
$adsi = [adsi]"LDAP://$group"
$members = foreach($member in $adsi.member) {
    $isUser = [adsi]"LDAP://$member"
    if('person' -in $isUser.objectclass) {
        $isUser.samaccountname
    }
}
```

Similar as the one above, but using `adsisearcher`, not sure which one would be more efficient in this case:

```
$members = foreach($member in $adsi.member) {
    $check = [adsisearcher]"(&(distinguishedname=$member)(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))"
    if($isUser = $check.FindOne()) {
        $isUser.Properties.samaccountname
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried both codeblocks but I do not get any return. I also get no error message. I copied your code and just changed de DN...

Comment: @user18209625 did you check the `$members` variable after running? Neither code block actually returns anything to the console

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thanks, I assumed that would be self-explanatory (I was wrong clearly)

Comment: Yes, I checked it

Answer (score 0):

I ran this modified version of your code on my own system, so I could see what the search string actually looked like:

```
$Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://DN of the AD group"
$Group.Member | ForEach-Object {
    $searchKey = "(samAccountName=$_)"
    $searchKey
    $Searcher = [adsisearcher]$searchKey 
    # $searcher.FindOne().Properties
}
```

Note the point where I let `$searchKey` come to the console. When I do this, I see values with *the full distinguished name* instead of just `samAccountName`. Based on this result I changed the code to look for that value instead of `samAccountName`, and then I saw (presumably) expected results:

```
$Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://DN of the AD group"
$Group.Member | ForEach-Object {
    $Searcher = [adsisearcher]"(distinguishedName=$_)"
    $searcher.FindOne().Properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$group = 'CN=myGroup, OU=myOU, DC=myDomain'
$adsi = [adsi]"LDAP://$group"
$members = foreach($member in $adsi.member) {
$isUser = [adsi]"LDAP://$member"
if('person' -in $isUser.objectclass) {
$isUser.samaccountname
}
}
$members
```